# Stacked bars first segment botched

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, bar-chart

I want to create normalized stacked bar graphs in my document. Somehow the first segment of the bar graphs gets botched, though. What causes this error?

### My Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
55,10,1,2,10
52,4,2,3,1
%18,0,2,3,4
%....
}\data

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
 create col/expr={
    \thisrow{1} + \thisrow{2} + \thisrow{3} + \thisrow{4}
 }
]{sum}{\data}

\newcommand{\stackedbar}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked, 
    point meta=\thisrow{y},
    table/y expr=\coordindex,
    table/x expr=\thisrow{y}/\thisrow{sum},
%    x filter/.append expression={\thisrow{0} == #1 ? x : nan},
    nodes near coords,
]
    \addplot table[y=1]{\data};
    \addplot table[y=2]{\data};
    \addplot table[y=3]{\data};
    \addplot table[y=4]{\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\stackedbar{55}
%\stackedbar{52}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Botched output with first segments only half drawn and weird offset labels]

As one can see the first segments are somehow partially drawn, but the segments' centers may be correctly computed (the weird label position on the left of the graph).

### Mysterious self repair

Interestingly enough, if I comment in the last line of the table, the other lines repair themselves and now get drawn, correctly.
[image: Including the last line of the table, the other ones get shown correctly]

---

(I left my intended usage of the `stackedbar` environment commented out in the code. I want to use the environment inline and filter out only one line of the table at a time.)

Comment: I do not know what you try to achieve, but maybe you want `xmin=0`.

Comment: I have not spend time understanding your code or what it does. If the single options solves your problem, feel free to add an answer. -but please also consider if your code or question+answer could help others in a similar situation?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @hpekristiansen, `xmin=0` fixes the problem, when included as an axis option.

I append my intended usage and output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
55,10,1,2,10
52,4,2,3,1
18,0,2,3,4
%....
}\data

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
 create col/expr={
    \thisrow{1} + \thisrow{2} + \thisrow{3} + \thisrow{4}
 }
]{sum}{\data}

\newcommand{\stackedbar}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked, 
    point meta=\thisrow{y},
    table/y expr=\coordindex,
    table/x expr=\thisrow{y}/\thisrow{sum},
    xmin=0,
    x filter/.append expression={\thisrow{0} == #1 ? x : nan},
    nodes near coords,
    ticks=none,
    axis lines=none,
    inner sep = 0,
    outer sep = 0,
    width=1.095\linewidth,
    scale only axis,
]
    \addplot table[y=1]{\data};
    \addplot table[y=2]{\data};
    \addplot table[y=3]{\data};
    \addplot table[y=4]{\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
This is what I wanted to achieve: show a single data row inline.\\
\stackedbar{55}\\
\lipsum[1]
This is what I wanted to achieve: show another data row inline.\\
\stackedbar{52}\\
\lipsum[2-3]\\
\stackedbar{18}
\end{document}
```

[image]